# Linux Ubuntu Lucid doesn't detect my second graphics card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, x-server

Since I have upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, my second graphics card isn't detected by X server.  When I do an `lspci` I get both listed though.

What could be the issue?

I am using NVidia's driver v195.36.24

Comment: Ubuntu Upgrade doesn't always go well,you might want to do a fresh install and see if that happens with the fresh install too

Comment: Why do you believe that it wasn't detected?

Comment: Because 'nvidia-settings' doesn't report a second gpu.

Comment: I also did a fresh install with the same result...

Answer (score 1):

Try this shell command (may need to be root, may need to add path to nvidia-xconfig to PATH):

```
nvidia-xconfig --sli=Auto
```

Comment: nothing happened at first time nor after reboot.